# How can I detect patch at strip image?

Tags: image, opencv, object-detection, android

Im detecting patches squares at strip image

I think boundaries are not clear

How can i get this patches clearly

please help me

this is my code and images

Thanks

---

### Code

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.src2);
//        bmp = changeBitmapContrastBrightness(bmp, (float)1.5, 0);

        Mat src = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, src);

        // Creating an empty matrix to store the result
        Mat dst = new Mat();

        // Creating kernel matrix
        Mat kernel = Mat.ones(1,1, CvType.CV_32F);

        for(int i = 0; i<kernel.rows(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<kernel.cols(); j++) {
                double[] m = kernel.get(i, j);

                for(int k = 1; k<m.length; k++) {
                    m[k] = m[k]/(2 * 2);
                }
                kernel.put(i,j, m);
            }
        }
        Imgproc.filter2D(src, dst, -1, kernel);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // Preparing the kernel matrix object
        Mat kernel1 = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT,
                new  Size((2*2) + 1, (2*2)+1));
        Imgproc.dilate(dst, dst, kernel1);

        Imgproc.threshold(dst, dst, 160, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

        // Creating kernel matrix
        Mat kernel2 = Mat.ones(5,5, CvType.CV_32F);
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(dst, dst, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, kernel2);
}
```

```
private static List<MatOfPoint> contourFind(Mat img){
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Imgproc.findContours(img, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        List<MatOfPoint> squares = new ArrayList<>();

        for(MatOfPoint cnt: contours){
            MatOfPoint2f curve = new MatOfPoint2f(cnt.toArray());
            MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(curve, approxCurve, 0.02 * Imgproc.arcLength(curve, true), true);

            int numberVertices = (int) approxCurve.total();

            double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(cnt);

            if (Math.abs(contourArea) < img.size().area() / 10){
                squares.add(cnt);
            }
        }

        return squares;
    }
```

---

### Original Image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SdC6.jpg)

---

### After process Image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puTqZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at some segmentation algorithm and train your model based on sample images for each category. There are algorithms like the Watershed algorithm for classical Machine learning. Or look at semantic segmentation if you can use deep learning and neural networks.